# Picture files cannot be opened directly by double clicking

Tags: windows-7, file-association, default-settings

When double-clicking a picture file, it shows
[image]

Then I choose "Select a program from a list of installed programs", and the "Windows Photo Viewer" is still there. I also check the "Always use the selected program to open this kind of file". 
[image]

It can ultimately be opened. But when I open it the next time, the same thing happens again.

I go to "Control Panel\Programs\Default Programs\Set Associations", but could not find any extensions for the picture format, e.g. png, jpg, jpeg, etc!
[image]

Comment: Does the user you are trying this with have admin rights?  Is this a corporate computer that might have Active Directory settings which are overriding your choice?

Comment: I am using my personal PC so with admin rights.